# How to join and filter with an aggregate in fluent query and retain json structure?

Tags: php, json, laravel, aggregate, fluent

I've been trying to get my models to play nicely with an aggregate statement in Laravel (4.2), but to no avail. When I use 'join', the nested json structure empties of its records. It's based around loans and payments.
Here's a simplified schema:

payments: id | loan_id | paid | expected
loans:    id | collectiontype_id | principal_amount

I need to find out if an account is in arrears and by how much, as well as displaying past payments.

Here are the models:

**Loan.php**

```
public function payment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Payment');
}
```

**Payment.php**

```
public function loan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Loan');
}
```

Performing the following gives me all the data I need for the payments:

```
Loan::with('collectiontype','payment')->get();
```

At one point I had the following in the Loan model:

```
public function payAggregate()
{

    return $this->hasOne('Payaggregate','loan_id','id')
                ->select(DB::raw("loan_id, count(*) as count, sum(expected) as sumexpected, sum(paid) as sumpaid, (sum(expected) - sum(paid)) as arrears"))
                ->groupBy('loan_id')
                ->having('arrears','>',10); 
}
```

Which worked well in isolation. However, when I tried to do a 'with':

```
Loan::with('collectiontype','payment','payaggregate')->get();
```

It worked without the having clause, but not with. I've tried 'has', 'whereHas' and many weird and wonderful things, but none of them seem to work for me.

I then thought of manually creating with using joins:

```
$v= DB::table('loans AS l')
    ->select(array('l.*', 'p.arrears','ct.shortlabel','pay.paid', 'pay.expected'))
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT loan_id, count(*) as count, sum(expected) as sumexpected, sum(paid) as sumpaid, (sum(expected) - sum(paid)) as arrears FROM payments GROUP BY loan_id) AS p'), function( $query ){
        $query->on( 'l.id', '=', 'p.loan_id' );
                    })
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM collectiontypes) AS ct'), function( $query ){
        $query->on( 'l.actualcollection', '=', 'ct.id' );
    })
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM payments) AS pay'), function( $query ){
        $query->on( 'l.id', '=', 'pay.loan_id' );
    })  
    ->where('p.arrears', '>', 10)->paginate(30);

$v->getCollection()->toJson();
```

However this just gave a flat output without the nested payments object. I hope I've articulated the issue clearly.